# Google App Scripts - Last modified date not being updated on every save

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to detect when a spreadsheet is modified using Google App Script on the current sheet.

My code is as follows

```
  var fileID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
  return file.getLastUpdated();
```

This does indeed bring back a date, however this doesn't seem to actually update on every save, it seems to only update about every minute or so.

Is this correct or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I think that such situation might be the specification. So as a workaround, how about using the event triggers of OnEdit and/or OnChange? By using the event triggers, when the Spreadsheet is modified, you can retrieve the date as the last modified date. How about this? Because I'm not sure whether this is what you want, I posted this proposal as a comment.

Comment: The problem I am trying to solve it to work out when someone else modified the spreadsheet I run a function to update the current user. The on edit and on change only run on the actual user performing the operation so this wouldn’t cover other users. I suppose I could maybe update some meta data somewhere and then poll this, I was hoping to not have to do though as it wouldn’t cover anyone not running the add on

Comment: I apologize I couldn't help.

Comment: No need to apologise, thanks for spending the time trying to help :)